# Confusion about group `cdrom` in linux system

Tags: devices, group, data-cd

When I type command `groups ubuntu`, the output would we like,

```
ubuntu : ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev admin
```

I am interested in the `cdrom` group. What does the group `cdrom` mean? It means user `ubuntu` can use `cdrom` device in the OS? If a user who is not in the group `cdrom`, can he/she use `cdrom` device in the OS?

Answer (score 1):

Use CD-ROM drives
This right is gained by adding the user to the "cdrom" group.

The "cdrom" group owns the CD-ROM devices in /dev.

so users can control cd/dvd device.